# Redcarpet for Jekyll (GithubPages) does not work

Tags: jekyll, syntax-highlighting, redcarpet

I'm trying to set up syntax highlighting for my Jekyll page using redcarpet but I can't get it to work. If I try it out I always see that still **rogue** is being used. This is how my `_config.yml` looks like:

```
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables", "with_toc_data"]
highlighter: redcarpet
markdown: redcarpet
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed the guidelines both on the redcarped webpage and on the Jekyll webpage.

This is the fenced code block I have in my test markdown file `test.md`

````
```java
class Foo {

    public void bar() {

    }

}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll hasn't supported redcarpet since May 2016 (source: https://github.com/blog/2151-github-pages-drops-support-for-rdiscount-redcarpet-and-redcloth-textile-markup-engines).

The only parser they support is kramdown. You'll either need to change to kramdown, or build your site locally and commit the output instead.